# [apache-flink]how to submit different flink jobs to different yarn clusters

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, jobs

I have 2 projects, each one should use a single cluster, but I don't know how to submit job to different YARN cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use the 
 -m,--jobmanager 
Address of the JobManager (master) to which to connect. Use this flag to connect  to a different JobManager than the one specified in the configuration.

It does not work.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and with which version of flink?